# Singleton initialization at compile-time

Tags: c++, c++11

I was just thinking if the new C++11 in-class member initializers could be used to initialize Singletons at compile-time, which might be a speed-up for some Manager-Classes in my applications:

```
class CSingleton
{
public:
    CSingleton(void) {}
    ~CSingleton(void) {}
    static const CSingleton* GetInstance(void)
    {
        return Instance;
    }

    bool Foo1(int x);
    bool Foo2(int y);
private:
    static constexpr CSingleton *Instance = new CSingleton();
}
```

The problem is this results in following errors:

```
Line of Instance declaration:    error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class test::CSingleton'
First Line of class declaration: error: forward declaration of 'class test::CSingleton'
```

Is there a way to initialize Singletons during compile-time with this or another approach?

[I am using GCC4.7 on MacOSX10.7 (and Ubuntu) with -std=c++0x flag set]

Comment: This class doesn't look much like a singleton...

Comment: Apart from the incomplete type issue, how do you expect the call to `operator new` to be executed at compile time?

Comment: @Job totally missed that point. thanks

Comment: You cannot initialize a variable at compile-time because variable only exist at runtime. You are probably looking for the term *static initialization*.

Comment: A `constexpr` singleton is a very peculiar idea... A singleton is, by design, a glorified global variable. A `constexpr` object does not vary. I think you were looking for a `constexpr` **constructor**.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Actually you can initialize a variable at compile time: http://pastebin.com/TN5XLnhh

Comment: @bames53: No. The computation may happen at compile-time, but the memory cell is initialized during *static initialization* which is part of loading the binary into memory.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Okay, I see what you're saying. In the sense of the C++ definition of object creation and lifetime the on disk representation isn't technically an initialized C++ object. So you're right. But in a more general sense, the object can exist on disk, and that object is initialized as a consequence of compilation and not program initiation.

Comment: @bames53: yes, so the value is computed during compilation, which is certainly quite handy (especially for templates which require compile-time values).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

in .h file member of class:

```
static CSingleton s_Instance;
```

in .cpp file in the begining right after include

```
CSingleton::s_Instance = CSingleton();
```

This is initialization in compile time.
using new - this is initialization in runtime. Formally both of them initialization in compile time.

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for. Can't believe I didn't manage to do that myself...

Comment: Formally, this is initialised at program startup, not compile time. If you use static objects, then beware the [initialisation order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14).

Comment: @Mike even `extern` objects suffer from that fiasco, unfortunately. Only bare array initialization can avoid these things.

Comment: @rubenvb: Indeed; by "static", I meant static storage duration (which includes `extern`), not static linkage or static memberness. It's a shame that "static" means so many different things in C++.